Is this verse present in bori critical edition mahabarata?
Mahabharata, Shanti Parva, 12:342:23.:
I (Krishna/Narayana) am the Soul, O son of Pandu (Arjuna), of all the worlds, of all the universe. Rudra, again, is my Soul. It is for this that I always adore him. If I do not adore that Shiva, the boon-giving Isana nobody would then adore my own self.”

Yes. Krishna says that he is the soul of all beings.

Rudra is Kapardi, Jatila and Munda. His house is the cremation ground.
He is a yogi who engages in fierce vows. He was terrible for Tripura.
He destroyed Daksha’s sacrifice and uprooted Bhaga’s eyes. O
Pandaveya! From one yuga to another yuga, know that Narayana is
always present in his atman. O Partha! Therefore, if Maheshvara, the
god of the gods, is worshipped, that is the same thing as the lord
god, Narayana, being worshipped. O descendant of the Pandu lineage!
I am the atman of all the worlds. Therefore, I single-mindedly worship Rudra as my own self. If Ishana Shiva, the granter of boons,
is not worshipped, then I think of that as my own self not being
worshipped. The worlds follow my ordinances. Those ordinances must be
honoured and I also honour them. A person who knows him, knows me. A
person who knows me, knows him. O Kounteya! Rudra and Narayana
possess a single essence, although they divide themselves into two,
pervade people and make them engage in all the acts. O descendant of
the Pandava lineage! There is no one else who is capable of granting
me a boon. In ancient times, I mentally thought this and worshipped
the great-souled lord of the universe, for the sake of obtaining a
son. There is no other god that Vishnu bows down before, with the
exception of Rudra, who is my own self. Therefore, I worship him.
Brahma, the Rudras, Indra and the rishis worship the god who is
foremost among the gods, Narayana Hari. O descendant of the Bharata
lineage! Among creatures of the past, the present and the future,
Vishnu is the foremost and he must always be served and worshipped.
Bow down before Vishnu, the one to whom havya is offered. Bow down
before the one who is the refuge.


Chapter 1656 (328), Moksha-Dharma Parva, Mahabharata, BORI.


Thanks for the answer
